# Error "ERROR: build failed with an exception." when starting the application

Tags: flutter, dart

**Here is the error on normal startup:**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Flutter_Projects\hazyaeva\build\app\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar: ������� �� ����� �������� ������ � �����, ��� ��� ���� ���� ����� ������ ���������.
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> BUILD FAILED in 17s
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

**Here is the error when run with --scan:**

> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
> WARNING: [Processor] Library 'C:\Users\knyzs.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.adcolony\sdk\4.6.5\818fbdf875a91af407c3faa9bfea044f05101168\sdk-4.6.5.aar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.
> Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/annotation/NonNull'
> Example of support library reference: 'android/support/annotation/NonNull'
> WARNING: [Processor] Library 'C:\Users\knyzs.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\co.ogury.module\ogury-ads\4.0.8\94966c91ef3621776c9d9120756adb9dee98043f\ogury-ads-4.0.8.aar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.
> Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager'
> Example of support library reference: 'android/support/annotation/VisibleForTesting'

> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
> C:\Flutter_Projects\hazyaeva\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-81 Warning:
> uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:18 to replace another declaration but no other declaration present

> Task :appodeal_flutter:generateDebugRFile
> WARNING: [Processor] Library 'C:\Users\knyzs.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.smaato.android.sdk\module-core\21.6.3\b33ec464a5b19d1333070ffce35630f249e2f621\module-core-21.6.3.aar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.
> Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/annotation/NonNull'
> Example of support library reference: 'android/support/annotation/Nullable'
> WARNING: [Processor] Library 'C:\Users\knyzs.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.adcolony\sdk\4.6.4\372a410fc325e819baf2817320b5bd369754d2a9\sdk-4.6.4.aar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.
> Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/annotation/NonNull'
> Example of support library reference: 'android/support/annotation/Nullable'
> WARNING: [Processor] Library 'C:\Users\knyzs.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\co.ogury.module\ogury-ads\4.0.7\ecb17275d328f6bf1f62b9d15a462c20ca76877b\ogury-ads-4.0.7.aar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.
> Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager'
> Example of support library reference: 'android/support/annotation/VisibleForTesting'
> WARNING: [Processor] Library 'C:\Users\knyzs.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.startapp\inapp-sdk\4.8.11\86a5ddbbdb68c26f2913d7a5d073e653abbe5e1b\inapp-sdk-4.8.11.aar' contains references to both AndroidX and old support library. This seems like the library is partially migrated. Jetifier will try to rewrite the library anyway.
> Example of androidX reference: 'androidx/annotation/Nullable'
> Example of support library reference: 'android/support/annotation/Nullable'

> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Flutter_Projects\hazyaeva\build\app\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar: ╨Я╤А╨╛╤Ж╨╡╤Б╤Б ╨╜╨╡ ╨╝╨╛╨╢╨╡╤В ╨┐╨╛╨╗╤Г╤З╨╕╤В╤М ╨┤╨╛╤Б╤В╤Г╨┐ ╨║ ╤Д╨░╨╣╨╗╤Г, ╤В╨░╨║ ╨║╨░╨║ ╤Н╤В╨╛╤В ╤Д╨░╨╣╨╗ ╨╖╨░╨╜╤П╤В ╨┤╤А╤Г╨│╨╕╨╝ ╨┐╤А╨╛╤Ж╨╡╤Б╤Б╨╛╨╝

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2m 35s
128 actionable tasks: 127 executed, 1 up-to-date

**How to fix it?**

Answer (score 0):

@Alexandr

It's failing because you have integrated some package in your application that is not compatible with the gradle version you have been using.

On Android studio, you can check your gradle version by : `Open the project` (If you are using Flutter, my suggestion would be to Click Open Existing project and then just choose the android directory inside your project's root) `> File > Project Structure`

You can either make that package compatible with your version of gradle (Probably be editing its `MainActivity.kt` file)

OR

Use a lower version of gradle (You can change this by going to `andoid/build.gradle`..Look for a line like this : `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'` Here 4.1.0 means gradle v6.7

Try a few values and If you are lucky everything would work just fine! :)